# how to set vue loading component on App.vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I want to add loader to my app.vue which is located in the main.js.
the error component loads fine when i set the timeout to something like 5ms.
However the delay does not seem to have any effect on the loading component, it does not show the loading component at all.

```js
import { createApp, defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';
import loadScreen from '@components/companyLoader.vue'
const App = defineAsyncComponent({
  loader: () => import('./App.vue'),
  delay: 200,
  timeout: 3000,
  loadingComponent: loadScreen,
  errorComponent: loadScreen, //runs when timeout set to 5ms
})



const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the cause is, but I have a workaround. Tested on Vue `v3.2.8`. You will need a wrapper component that you load normally (`AppWrapper`) and an internal component that you load asynchronously (`App`).

You can manually detect when a component is loaded with this small function:

```js
/** Returns a promise that resolves when the async component is loaded. */
const componentLoaded = (asyncComponent, pollFrequency = 100) =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    const timerRef = {}
    timerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      if (asyncComponent.__asyncResolved) {
        clearInterval(timerRef.current)
        resolve(asyncComponent.__asyncResolved)
      }
    }, pollFrequency)
  })
```

Just set `this.loaded` on the containing component (`AppWrapper`) when the async component (`App`) is loaded:

```
  created() {
    componentLoaded(App).then(() => {
      this.loaded = true
    })
  },
```

And then use `loaded` to conditionally render a loading component:

```js
  <v-if="!loaded" LoadingComponent />
  <App />
```

(Note that you cannot use `v-else` on `<App>`, as it will prevent the async component from loading at all. It needs to render in order to load asynchronously. You can use `v-show`.)

Comment: I did something similar in the end. I just ended up making the App.vue take a child component with the loader in there instead. still not sure why this is a problem, when you look at the chunks it produces it should work because the vue core is separate from the components